# upgrade and migrate from oracle 11.4 to 19c

Tags: oracle11g, migration, upgrade, oracle19c, datapump

We have are currently on oracle 11.2 Linux OS 7.0 and we want to upgrade to 19c Linux OS 8.0 on new servers. My thought process was that we should do an in place upgrade from 11.2 to 19c and then migrate the data to the new server but I don't have a work flow (SOP, procedure). What do you suggest? And do you have any documentation?

Comment: This thread on OCN might give you some ideas: https://community.oracle.com/mosc/discussion/4512686/migration-from-oracle-11-2-to-19#latest

Comment: Thanks pmdba I will check it out